# No such module "CreateMLUI"

Tags: xcode, xcode10, macos-mojave, createml, createmlui

I am using macOS Mojave Beta (10.14 18A293u) and Xcode 10.0 Beta (10L176w). I created a Swift Playground and I am unable to import `CreateMLUI` framework in order to use it. I keep getting an import error.

[image: Playground Screenshot]

I have tried creating both an **iOS Playground** and a **macOS Playground**

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some suggestions in this thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/314438#314438

Comment: Thanks @Koen found a working solution in that link you provided, will. be posting it as an answer! Thanks again.

Answer (score 48):

While macOS Mojave and Xcode 10 are in beta you may experience bugs while trying to use CreateML.

@Koen from one of the comments in my question found a topic in Apple  Developer Forums with some workarounds. What I did was:

1. Create a new single view **Mac OS (NOT iOS)** playground
2. Use a completely different name if already created a buggy playground (this is important)
3. Add the `import CreateMLUI` line
4. Remove all the other boilerplate code

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to this problem in the apple developers forum (Can't find the exact link to the post).
You simply have to select the macOS tab when creating a playground.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the playground make sure you select "macOS" tab instead of. "iOS".

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `Xcode menu`
2. Choose `Open Developer Tool` > `Create ML`
3. Press `New Document`
4. Select `Image Classification`
5. Specify name and a place where the project will be saved

Answer (score 1):

This feature is no longer supported in this environment. You can complete this task in the Create ML app. Follow these steps:

> Xcode -> Toolbar -> Open Developer Tool -> Create ML -> New Document

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of macOS, the CreateMLUI library has been deprecated and removed.  Instead, create models in CreateML, a developer application inside Xcode.